# How to play a video before/over top of GDM in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, video, gdm, plymouth

On my PC running Ubuntu 20.04, I want to play a video before GDM starts/over top of it. Not after logging in, but that.

Is there any way to make Ubuntu autoplay a video in the plymouth screen before I log in?

Comment: Do you want to play the video instead of Ubuntu logo (i.e. the splash screen)? Or do you want to use it as a standalone video player and do not want the login screen to ever show up?

Comment: I want it to play, then show the login screen. So the first option I guess.